# The category of affine schemes is anti-equivalent to the category of commutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, affine-schemes

The category of affine schemes is anti-equivalent to the category of commutative rings.

Let $F$ be the contravariant functor from the category of commutative rings (with identity) to affine schemes such that $F(R)=(\text{Spec}R,\mathscr{O}_{\text{Spec}R})$
and $F(\phi)=(π,\pi^{\#}):(\text{Spec}R,\mathscr{O}_{\text{Spec}R})\to  (\text{Spec}S,\mathscr{O}_{\text{Spec}S})$ for a homomorphism $\phi :S \to R$.

Where $$\pi \colon \text{Spec}R \longrightarrow \text{Spec}S,\ 
P \longmapsto \phi^{-1}(P)$$
is a continuous map from topological space $\text{Spec}R$ to topological space $\text{Spec}S$ and $\pi^{\#}$ is a sheaf morphism
$$\pi^{\#}: \mathscr{O}_{\text{Spec}S} \to \pi_{\ast}\mathscr{O}_{\text{Spec}R}$$
which is induced by the ring homeomorphism.

$\phi_f:R_f\to S_{\phi (f)}$, for an open set $X_f$ of $\text{Spec}S$

- $ \pi_{\ast}\mathscr{F} :=  \mathscr{F}(\pi^{-1}(V)), \: \text{for every open} \: V\subset Y.$
- $ R_f \: \text{is the ring localization of }R\text{ at } f$

Now we define the contravariant functor $G$ from  the category of affine schemes to the category of commutative rings such that $$G((\text{Spec}R,\mathscr{O}_{\text{Spec}R}))=\Gamma (\text{Spec}R,\mathscr{O}_{\text{Spec}R})=R.$$

**This is where I stuck:**

and for a morphism $(π,\pi^{\#}):(\text{Spec}R,\mathscr{O}_{\text{Spec}R})\to  (\text{Spec}S,\mathscr{O}_{\text{Spec}S})$,

$G((π,\pi^{\#}))=?$

somehow we need to induce a ring homomorphism $\phi^{\ast} :\Gamma(\text{Spec}S,\mathscr{O}_{\text{Spec}S})=S\to R= \Gamma(\text{Spec}R,\mathscr{O}_{\text{Spec}R})$

I just don't know how to produce $\phi^{\ast} $ from a given morphism of affine schemes.

Can someone explain to me how we do this?

Can I find somewhere an explicit proof of the theorem ?

Comment: This is in every algebraic geometry text. Did you look? The relevant gadget even starts with a "G".

Comment: @KReiser I checked Eisenbud's the geometry of schemes, and it wasn't mentioned I also checked Tennison's book which it did, but the motive was very unclear as the proof itself...

Comment: @lupusnox This is Theorem I-40 in Eisenbud and Harris, and proposition II.2.3 in Hartshorne.

Comment: @DavidLui I now get that $G(π,π^{\#})=π^{\#}_U$. Could you explain how from the local map $φ_P:R_P\to S_{φ(P)} $ we get the sheaf morphism $π^{\#}$ ?

Comment: I assume you take global sections.  More importantly, affine schemes are *defined* so as to be equivalent to commutative rings with identity.  The whole point is to take a ring $R$ and produce a space $X$ so that $R$ is the ring of functions on $X$.  For a proof, see Theorem 1 and Corollary 1 of II.2 in the red book (Mumford).